# FireBreath find system path

Tags: npapi, firebreath, filepath

I'm new to firebreath and I am developing an NPAPI plugin to be packaged to a Google Chrome Extension. I am having troubles with creating a method that retrieves where the DLL is currently in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy; you can find instructions on the [Tips and Tricks](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Tips+and+Tricks#TipsandTricks-GettingthepathandfilenameofthepluginDLLsoordylib) page of the FireBreath website:

```
// From inside your Plugin class (that extends PluginCore)
std::string MyPlugin::getFilesystemPath()
{
    return m_filesystemPath;
}
```